# Interchange values' index in an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, indexing

I'm trying to interchange index of values in an array to make the array store them in descending order. But the output isn't as desired. I entered values in multiple arrays in ascending order and then merged them into an array "result"(values still being in ascending order), now I wish to interchange the values' index in array "result" to make it store them in descending order. The logic I've thought of is below;

```
for(int i=0, j=ind-1; i<ind; j--,i++) //ind is index of array "result"
{
  result[i]=result[j];
}
for (int final = 0; final < end; final++)
{
  cout << result[final] << " ";
}
```

I don't want to use is_sort or any other function.

Comment: Why not use functions? `std::swap` is the perfect solution to your problem

Comment: it's a condition, i can't

Answer (score 1):

Interchange operations is wrong. The best option is to use an auxiliar variable:

```
  auto aux = result[j];
  result[j] = result[i];
  result[i] = aux;
```

Comment: Or even better: `std::swap(result[j],result[i]);` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap )

Comment: i said you cant use functions. how can i do it using loop?

Answer (score 0):

well first you don't have to iterate over the whole array just half of it since you are swapping otherwise you would be swapping twice so nothing changes

second that's the correct(basic) way to swap two array elements

```
for(int i=0, j=ind-1; i<j; j--,i++) //ind is index of array "result"
{
  auto temp=result[i];
  result[i]=result[j];
  result[j]=temp;
}
```

if you want to iterate 1/2 array, you can do

```
j=(int)ind/2
```

see [casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) for more info.